# Laravel: How to validate one model before save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

For example, i have two models:

```
Product
```

and

```
ProductSpec
```

**ProductSpec** is a specification of **Product** and your *primary key* is the same of Product.

So, when i go to save ProductSpec, i do:

```
$product = new Product;
$product->name = $name;
$product->save();

$productSpec = new ProductSpec;
$productSpec->product_id = $product->id;
$productSpec->value = $value;
$success = $productSpec->save();

// in case of ProductSpec validation errors
if ( $success !== true ) {
  $product->delete();
}
```

My validations rules is in the model. The problem is when i have some validation errors on **ProductSpec** saving, the application is aborted and i cant delete the **Product** model.

Please, How solve this? or there is another way to validate ProductSpec before, if true, save it?

Comment: I think when you save the data the in the products model get the id of that and insert that in the product spec. Then compare their id's

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap both operations in a single **database transaction**. This way either both objects will be saved or none.

This will do the trick:

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($name, $value) {
  $product = new Product;
  $product->name = $name;
  $product->save();

  $productSpec = new ProductSpec;
  $productSpec->product()->associate($product);
  $productSpec->value = $value;
  $productSpec->save();
});
```

You can read more about transactions in Eloquent here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#database-transactions

Comment: Good! but not working for me. when a validation exception is thrown in ProductSpec, transaction is not rolled back

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi Note that for MySQL, only InnoDB and DBD engines support database transactions. If you're using MyISAM, this will not work for you.

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 With laravel transaction no. I'm using OctoberCMS that implements Laravel and when occurs a (rules) validation error is throw new `ModelException`. So, without transaction i did:  
`// (..) $product->save();
try 
{
   $productSpec->save()
}catch( ModelException $e) 
{
   $product->delete();
   $validationErrors = $productSpec->errors()->all();
}`